# htaccess is slowing down my site significantly

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I have this PHP application which was working fine , but ever since I have used htaccess the speed of the page has reduced significantly, and sometimes it doesn't even load at all. Also if I manage to open the page by restarting the apache server , the page loads up but without any JS.

Below is my htaccess code.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-!@#$&()\\-`.+,/\"]+)/?$ /var/www/html/25_2_april/video.php?cat_id=$1&category=$2  [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /var/www/html/25_2_april/search_results.php?cat_id=$1  [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-!@#$&()\\-`.+,/\"]+)/?$ /var/www/html/25_2_april/video-detail.php?vid_id=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

Comment: I don't know what you want to achieve, but this cannot work, because substitutions cannot be file system paths in an .htaccess file.

Comment: i want to make clean URL . For eg : this was my original URL `localhost/25_2_april/video.php?cat_id=12&category=Java` and i want to convert it into `localhost/25_2_april/12/Java`. Now the follwoing htaccess code helped me do that , but the speed has drastically decreased. and sometimes it's not even loading .

Comment: First, I would remove `/var/www/html` from the substitution. Although, I wouldn't expect this to speed up anything.

Comment: but if i remove `/var/www/html` then the htaccess dosen't work . That's the reason i had to give the complete path.